# Date format for Django Admin

Tags: django

I have a Model with `DateField`. In Django admin when I try to enter the date in Django Admin in format `%d-%m-%Y` it throws error as `Enter a valid date.`. Since the default pattern is `%Y-%m-%d`

I tried the following but couldnt find a satisfied solution over the docs:

1. Change the format type with strftime in model.
2. Add `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` in settings.
3. Change language code to "en-IN"

Is there any way to save the date in `%d-%m-%Y` format.

Comment: `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` does not work? Have you set `USE_L10N = True` in your settings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField('Date', null=True, blank=True)
```

Insert this in `Settings.py`

```
DATE_FORMAT = ( ( 'd-m-Y' ))
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ( ('%d-%m-%Y'),)
DATETIME_FORMAT = (( 'd-m-Y H:i' ))
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = (('%d-%m-%Y %H:%i'),)

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = False

USE_TZ = False
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#date-format  scroll page down to see more options.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go into your model and add a couple of line:

```
import datetime
class yourModel(models.model):
    date = field etc
    def __str__(self):
        return date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: I tried to add the __str__ but it throws as ```descriptor 'strftime' for 'datetime.date' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object```. Date can be convert to str for the moment?